# In a Django URL, what is the regular expression so that "foo.com/Bar" is the same as "foo.com/bar"

Tags: python, regex, django, case-sensitive

My problem is people keep linking to example.com/FooBar but the actual link is example.com/foobar.

My current regex is...

```
SLUG = '(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)'
```

I hope that makes sense. I was surprised I couldn't find this question already asked. Maybe my google fu is weak today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex matches both. The difficulty is that you've likely got a query like:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Which isn't matching.

To fix this, change the query to:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your query could be like

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug__icontains=slug)
```

The [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) field lookup will do a case insensitive match

Comment: I like this answer too because then I don't have to force that created url to be all lower case.

Comment: But, if I go to /foobar and multiple objects slugs contain 'foobar' so 'foobarA' or 'foobarb'.. it then returns multiple objects. I know I could do some more work to prevent this but yeah. It creates an issue.

Comment: @teewuane you can change the query to be 

obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)